# swift NSLocalizedString in else if

Tags: swift, button, translate, nslocalizedstring

i´am working on my first swift app. Now i like to translate the text from a BUTTON with NSLocalizedString, but i don´t know how to write it in swift.

Here is my else-if function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
if volumeBool {
    volumeOut.setTitle("SOUND ON", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
} else {
    volumeOut.setTitle("SOUND OFF", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
NSLocalizedString("string to translate", comment: "comment for the language file")
```

So in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if volumeBool {
        volumeOut.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("SOUND ON", comment: "Title for sound on"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } 
    else {
        volumeOut.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("SOUND OFF", comment: "Title for sound off"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: first, thanks a lot for your fast answer. One question. in the localized.string file. i tried `"Title for sound on" = "Ton an...";` and `"SOUND ON" = "Ton an..";` but none is working?

Comment: Try a clean build, sometimes Xcode misses the changed localized files: Product-->Clean, Product --> (Alt key) Clean build folder. Then recompile.

Comment: Note that the comment is only a hint for the translator, it shouldn't be translated.

Comment: i tried cleaning. my button is in every language SOUND ON and SOUND OFF. my other labels and buttons (without else-if statement) will be translated correctly this way. `"ksQ-33-yns.normalTitle" = "the translated text is correct";`. i don´t know what i´am doing wrong?